# Sqlite IDbConnection - BeginTransaction Execption

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, transactions, insert

I have a Sqlite/C# Application and want to start a transaction but i always get this execption:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   message=
>   The operation is invalid due to the current state of the object.
>   Quelle = System.Data.SQLite   Stapelüberwachung:    bei
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)    bei
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection.System.Data.IDbConnection.BeginTransaction()
>   bei CsvCompare.database.importCSVtoDB(List`1 clist, String table) in
>   C:\Users\Luis\source\repos\CsvCompare\CsvCompare\database.cs: Zeile40 
>   bei CsvCompare.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Luis\source\repos\CsvCompare\CsvCompare\Form1.cs: Zeile29
>   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    bei
>   CsvCompare.Program.Main() in
>   C:\Users\Luis\source\repos\CsvCompare\CsvCompare\Program.cs: Zeile19

I translated the execption. If you dont unterstand something then let me know.

Here is the code:

```
 public static void importCSVtoDB(List<customer> clist,string table)
        {
            string query = "";

            foreach (customer c in clist)
            {
                query +=  "INSERT INTO " + table + "(adress,name,zipcode,city) VALUES('" + c.adress + "','" + c.name + "'," + c.zipcode + ",'" + c.city + "');\n";
            }


            using (IDbConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(loadconnectionstring()))
            {
                db.BeginTransaction();
                db.Execute(query + "COMMIT;"); 

            }
        }
```

How i can solve this?

Comment: looks like `db.Open()` is simply missing.

Comment: you need to open the connection with `Open()` before starting executing the command to the DB

Comment: Oh ups! Yes this solved this problem! Thank you :) Now i can work on my main problem...the perfomance